# Change id from selected option

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have searched for similar questions but every question that was related wasn't the solution for me.

I am using php, sql and phpmyadmin for this.

I'm trying to add characters to a world. The idea is that you can add characters to a world by selecting them in option field(for now) and change the world_id of that character.

Now i have the id but i don't know how to actually change it in the database.

I will show my database

table characters:

```
id 
name
last_name
image
age 
world_id (this table is linked with the table worlds)
```

table worlds:

```
world_id (so the world_id's are linked
name
description
```

my php code:

```
                            $pdo = Database::connect();
                            $sql = 'SELECT * FROM characters ORDER BY id DESC';
                            echo '<select name="option">';
                                foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
                                    echo '<option value="' . $row['id'] . '">' . $row['name'] . '</option>';    
                                }
                            echo '</select>';
                            $selected_val = $_POST['option']; 

                        ?>
```

Hopefully can someone help me.

Comment: You need to learn how to do/use `UPDATE / INSERT` records in your database, plenty of guides on how to do that.

Comment: Is the `id` column an `auto increment, unique key`?

Comment: yes id is auto increment

Comment: i don't want to replace  the id's but the world_id in the character table is null and i want that columm be filed with the world id from table worlds so you can see which character is in which world

Comment: Ah woops, completely missed that, sorry

Comment: So just do an update then

Comment: its just an update but i guess i'm thinking to hard but how do i get that variable into a sql query  i mean $selected_val into a sql query

Comment: @Jessep try this- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18323065/update-query-with-pdo-and-mysql

Comment: Thank you ! i understand now thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run an update query in the database-

```
$sql = "UPDATE `characters` SET `world_id` = :world_id WHERE `id` = :id";
$world_id = 1; //any world id you want to set
$statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$statement->bindValue(":world_id", $selected_val);
$statement->bindValue(":id", $world_id);
$count = $statement->execute();
```